# WP7's background agent - how to run longer & how to communicate with?

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, background-process

I'm trying to implement a socket listener in Windows Phone 7.1, which should process the incoming data and make some actions based on it (constantly, without interrupting). As far as I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), the info described there confused a lot, so these are the questions:

1. Is there some ability for the background agent to be run constantly, without interrupting by the system (or with acceptable amount of running time, more than 10 minutes)?
2. Is there any API to communicate with running agent, something like Android's [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html)?

PS. I cannot use Push Notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, background agents cannot run constantly. If you need code to execute constantly then you should keep the app running, maybe enable running under lock screen if appropriate.
2. No, you cannot connect to an agent.

Agents are not like services.

Comment: That's no good... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Matt Lacey is there any inter process communication in WP7?

Comment: @Yamamoto If you have a new question you should ask it separately and include more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your sockets requirement sounds like you will run into the same problem presented by this question: [Windows Phone 7 (Mango) App gets disconnected when put in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6448302/3603)

1. [`PeriodTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is only executed every 30 minutes or so and thus cannot maintain a socket connection. You might want to look into running under the lock screen, as per [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548669/wp7s-background-agent-how-to-run-longer-how-to-communicate-with/6550077#6550077), or perhaps [`ResourceIntensiveTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.resourceintensivetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which can run for <strike>as long as you want</strike> [for 10 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) but *only while the phone is connected to power* and the phone has > 90% battery.
2. There is no API to communicate between the two but applications and their tasks share isolated storage, including databases.

Comment: Hm. Using isolated storage is a good idea, thank you. Will look what I can do.